# Wrong code indentation with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've noticed that when I use "Ctrl + K, Ctrl D" to automatically format a View, Visual Studio 2015 gives me this horrible result:

[image]

As you can see, the curly brackets are not aligned with "@Html.Partial". Instead, I would expect something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to correct this behaviour?

Comment: Indenting in a mix of languages is very tricky and has some bugs.

Comment: Check whitespace vs tabs settings